# Can Cortana control the radio?

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, cortana, radio

I have tried pressing to make her listen, it says "listening" but if I say "play radio" I just get a page of results from a web search for that phrase.

If I say "Launch FM Radio" then at least some of the time she does launch the app. However nothing further seems voice controllable - if the radio is paused, it doesn't care if I say "play" and certainly changing the channels isn't going to happen. If I try to embed a command to Cortana, like "launch FM Radio, Play" or "launch FM Radio and Play" we are just back in web search land.

Is it just something she can't do?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like this is currently not possible. You can request features through the Windows Feedback app for Windows 10 and Windows 10 Mobile - unfortuantely the [UserVoice](http://cortana.uservoice.com/) site is being phased out right now.